# Delete Specific Columns based on Conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to make a program that takes user input and stores the values in an array called FastenerNumbers.  Based on these values the program then fills specific cells with a green color so that the user knows to enter values there.  The thing is if a value in the array is 0 I would like to delete that column so that the worksheet is cleaner.

The issue I'm running into is that when a column is deleted during the for loop the cells shift left.  Because of this some of the cells are essentially skipped over.  To counteract this I've essentially had to brute force the program so that it loops several times to account for any skipped columns.

Here's the code:

```
'Make cells green for user to put inputs into
For i = 0 To UBound(FastenerNumbers)
    If FastenerNumbers(i) <> 0 Then
        With Range(Range("A14").Offset(0, 2 * i), Range("A14").Offset(FastenerNumbers(i) - 1, (2 * i) + 1))
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End With
    End If
Next

'Define initial counter variable
j = 1

'    Do Until j = 5
'        For i = 0 To UBound(FastenerNumbers)
'            If FastenerNumbers(i) = 0 Then
'                Range(Range("A14").Offset(0, 2 * i), Range("A14").Offset(FastenerNumbers(i) - 1, (2 * i) + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
'            End If
'        Next
'    Loop
'

Do
    For Each cell In Range("A14", Range("A14").Offset(, (UBound(FastenerNumbers) + 1) * 2))
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> 4 Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
        j = j + 1
        If j >= (5 * (UBound(FastenerNumbers) + 1) * 2) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Next
Loop
```

The pseudocode is another method I was going to use.  I don't think either method is significantly better than the other.  I would like the loops to be cleaner and more efficient though.

Comment: Instead of deleting the column, just hide it? Edit: or loop backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it as simple as having a separate variable (`j`) counting the number of valid `FastenerNumbers()` valueslike follows

```
'Make cells green for user to put inputs into
For i = 0 To UBound(FastenerNumbers)
    If FastenerNumbers(i) <> 0 Then
        With Range(Range("A14").Offset(0, 2 * j), Range("A14").Offset(FastenerNumbers(i) - 1, (2 * j) + 1)) ' use j as the column relevant variable
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End With
        j = j + 1 'update column relevant variable
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That seems to do what I want thanks!  I currently have the column titles in a separate part of the code so I'm going to have to fix some other things as well.  When I touch up my code at the end I'll change it to this so that it runs quicker though.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this so not entirely sure it works, but give this a shot.  Essentially it keeps everything within the `For` loop, and if `FastenerNumbers(i)` = 0 then it deletes the column, reduces `i` by 1, then continues to the next (in that case the same number):

```
For i = 0 To UBound(FastenerNumbers)
    If FastenerNumbers(i) <> 0 Then
        With Range(Range("A14").Offset(0, 2 * i), Range("A14").Offset(FastenerNumbers(i) - 1, (2 * i) + 1))
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End With
    Else
        Range(Range("A14").Offset(0, 2 * i), Range("A14").Offset(FastenerNumbers(i) - 1, (2 * i) + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Just tried it out.  I see the logic behind it.  It seems like the i-1 keeps resetting it though so that it's infinitely looping.

Comment: That makes sense actually, since it's looking at the values in the array, and the columns being deleted don't change the values in the array.  You could add in the `Else` statement something that removes that specific value from the array.  Off the top of my head not sure how you would go about that though

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  I'm not 100% sure how to do that either though.